# Possible to pass a constant to C# compiler in build script

Tags: c#, build, precompile

I have a C# file with something like this:

```
public const string QueueName = "abc";
```

and I would like to build the application several times switching this value each time. It is NOT possible to change `QueueName` to anything other than a compile-time constant.

Is there any way to pass a 'pre-compiler' variable to this declaration that could be changed in a build configuration or build script?

I have googled it but I can't seem to get any solution.

Comment: You could use a T4 template to generate the code for your constant.  In the T4 template it could read an environment variable, or a file, or.... to get the value to put in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are constants, you could consider using [code generation with a T4  template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate the constants and the values **on build** in a separate class file.

The proper constantvalues from this class file can come from an array, database or other external source.

Code would be something like:

```
   <#@ output extension=".cs" #>
    <#
       using(SampleContext context = new SampleContext)
       {
       string queuename = context.Queuename.FirstOrDefault();
       }
    #>
    internal class NotSoConstantConstants
    {
       public const string QueueName = "<#= queuename #>";
    }
```

which can output to:

```
internal class NotSoConstantConstants
{
  public const string QueueName = "abc";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a tool to do this, it allows injection of environment variables at build time.

I think it is a cleaner looking solution than T4, but really it is a personal preference.

Check out the project https://github.com/bonyjoe/EnvVariableInject